# SQL "Not Like '%%'" Conditional Insert/Update

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a conditional SQL statement executed via Powershell which inserts or updates a database based on the existence of rows. I'm using this script to inventory software. However, numerous security updates and hotfixes appear when the script runs, and I'd like to exclude these records from being placed in the SQL database as they don't qualify as applications. I've tried using a NOT LIKE clause a few different ways and I just can't get it working. I've tried using EXCEPT as well. Any advice is greatly appreciated! Code below with my last syntax attempt:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQLServer" -Database "$SqlDB" -query "UPDATE $SoftwareTable
SET name = N'$($CSVAppName -replace "'", "''")',
    version = N'$($CSVVersion -replace "'", "''")',
  product_id = N'$($CSVAppID -replace "'", "''")',
  arch = N'$($CSVArch -replace "'", "''")'
WHERE product_id = '$CSVAppIDgo'
WHERE name not like '%hotfix%' AND '%security update%';
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO $SoftwareTable (name, version, product_id, arch) 
    VALUES (N'$($CSVAppName -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVVersion -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVAppID -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVArch -replace "'", "''")')
    WHERE name not like '%hotfix%' AND '%security update%'"
}
```

Comment: change WHERE name not like '%hotfix%' AND '%security update%' to WHERE name not like '%hotfix%' AND name not like '%security update%' to exclude both.

Comment: I've tried this but get an Incorrect Syntax Near WHERE error. Could just be punctuation somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$SQLServer" -Database "$SqlDB" -query "UPDATE $SoftwareTable
SET name = N'$($CSVAppName -replace "'", "''")',
    version = N'$($CSVVersion -replace "'", "''")',
  product_id = N'$($CSVAppID -replace "'", "''")',
  arch = N'$($CSVArch -replace "'", "''")'
WHERE product_id = '$CSVAppIDgo'
and name not like '%hotfix%' 
AND name not like '%security update%';
IF @@ROWCOUNT=0
    INSERT INTO $SoftwareTable (name, version, product_id, arch) 
    VALUES (N'$($CSVAppName -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVVersion -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVAppID -replace "'", "''")', N'$($CSVArch -replace "'", "''")')
    WHERE name not like '%hotfix%' 
    AND name not like '%security update%'"
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but get an Incorrect Syntax Near WHERE error. Could just be punctuation somewhere?